# Speech recognition to login to web application

Tags: java, voice-recognition, voice

I am creating an web application where user should register the application through Voice recognition as password. The voice should be recognized for authorization. Is there any way to implement voice recognition through Java language?

PS: If user gives voice, then voice should able to recognize by already stored voice and able to login the application.

Comment: Please don't mix up voice and speech recognition tags, your topic is voice, not speech.

Answer (score 5):

To can store the audio data file as blob in data and use `inputStream` to read, this link might help [AudioSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html).

As for speaker recognition, it seems there aren't many "off the shelf" speaker recognition software stacks. A quick Google search yielded a few projects, so it is indeed possible. You should be able to find them, and learn by picking one and studying it.

Comment: ok..using this audio match will be used as authentication..Is this also support voice recognition as authentication i.e., voice of user should act as password?

Answer (score 0):

Web Speech API : http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

There's a way to use speech as an input password to login. You can match the data voice in your database with the voice with a little normalization.

And for that you can use web service and powered it with googleapis speech.
And may be this link can help for that : [Google Speech API still supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893564/google-speech-api-still-supported/)

Sorry, write this over android. Very messy... I'll edit this answer as soon as possible I get a PC...